# IIS URL Rewrite redirect all subdirectories

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

My website has a lot of old pages and directories not in use.  Instead of deleting them, I'm thinking about using the rewrite rules to redirect them to its parent directory,

For example, I have these links:

- `https://www.example.com/category/sub/1`
- `https://www.example.com/category/sub2222/1/a`
- `https://www.example.com/category/something/sub/3333`

I want all three of them to redirect to `https://www.example.com/category`.

I tried the code below but got into an infinite loop.  Guess I have to specify the rule do redirect ONLY when it has a subdirectory:

```
<rule name="Redirect-test" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="category/(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/category" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, maybe I was overthinking of this, adding a /(.*) would solve my problem, I'm just wondering if there's any flaws in such rule

```
<rule name="Redirect-test" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="category/(.*)/(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/category" />
</rule>
```